# Accessing Data Table Column Value for Use in Arithmetic Operartions

Tags: powershell

I have a data table (`System.Data.DataTable`) that is populated with data via load of a reader variable returned by executing a SQL query for a `System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand`.

While I am able to access the row column value to print it via the `Write-Host` cmdlet, I am unable to access the value to be used in arithmetic operations as in the example below.  I will note that the column in question is derived from the SQL `COUNT` function (see snippet below) and the type returned is `System.Int32`.

SQL Query snippet:

```
SELECT Day(Date) AS DayofWeek, Researcher_DisplayName, COUNT(Researcher_DisplayName) AS Total FROM ...
```

PowerShell code:

```
[int32] $sumTotal = 0

foreach ($Row in $resultsDataTable) {
    Write-Host ("Total value is: " + $Row["Total"]) # this line works, the value is printed
    $sumTotal = $sumTotal + $Row["Total"]           # this line does not work
}

Write-Host ("sumTotal value is: " + $sumTotal)       # value printed is 0
```

Comment: Is there any error message? What version of PowerShell is this? I've tested a similar construct under PS5 and it works ok for me in the way you've detailed. Are you sure $Row["Total"] is an int?

Comment: What about casting to `[int32]`? Try: `$sumTotal += [int32]$Row["Total"] `

Comment: I have already tried casting to [int32] and no luck...

Comment: running version 4.  Yes, I am sure the value in the data table is an Int